# When is variational inference really powerful

Tags: bayesian, variational-bayes

I'm learning VI, and specifically Coordinate Ascent Variational Inference, and I'm wondering when we actually get a strong benefit for this method.

In particular, the objective is:
$$
\min D_{KL}(q(\theta)||p(\theta||D))
$$
And the whole point is that we can minimize this distance without knowing $p(\theta||D)$

However, in most the examples I see around, the prior $p(\theta)$ is usually set to something very loose, such as $N(0,100)$ (or anyway, with a big $\sigma^2$)

Now, from a non-theorist-person, a prior $N(0,100)$ corresponds to a uniform prior pretty much, and we also know that:
$$
p(\theta|D) \approx p(D|\theta), \text{ given } p(\theta) = Uniform
$$

So, at that point, we can say that our posterior is pretty much our likelihood that we know how to calculate

Now, this point of view comes from a person with little experience from the world of Bayesian/variational inference, so I might definitely not be seeing something utterly wrong in what I'm seeing, so please, correct me if I'm wrong

The final question is: the whole point of VI was to approximate $p(\theta|D)$ without knowing it, though we usually use such a loose prior $p(\theta)$ that the posterior is almost equal to the likelihood, which we know how to calculate, and thus we can solve $\min D_{KL}(q(\theta)||p(D||\theta))$... however I have a sense that I'm missing something....

Comment: In your second part you write that with a uniform prior, then the posterior is the likelihood times a normalisation constant.  What is the question behind that second part of the post?

Comment: What so you mean by variational inference? Do you mean Bayesian inference?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus added the "final" question... I mean why do we need mean field/CAVI/all this tools that allows us to approximate the posterior, when that is pretty much the likelihood

Comment: The tools can also be helpful to compute the likelihood, and there might be an involvement of nuisance parameters that need to be integrated out.